# Autocompletion in YML files with Spring configuration doesn't work for map field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-configuration

I'm facing some issues with autocompletion feature for yml files containing spring configuration. I found very similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157155/spring-boot-expand-configuration-properties-metadata-json-hints-for-map-not-wo) but my reputation is too low to write a comment there. The solution doesn't work for me.

I enabled annotation processor [image]
I'm using the newest Ultimate version of IntelliJ.

I added the following dependency to my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I have two classes:

```java
public class BooProperties {
    private int workerCount;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("server.worker")
public class FooProperties {
    private int workerCount;
    private int subWorkerCount;
    private int limit;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Map<String, BooProperties> group = new HashMap<>();
    // getters and setters
}
```

My whole project can be found [here in github](https://github.com/PawelBogdan/configuration-demo).

Autocompletion works generally:
[image]

But it doesn't work for map keys (I also would like to work for values, but this is much too far right now)
[image]
Despite I added file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`:

```json
{
  "properties":[{
    "name": "server.worker.group",
    "type":"java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.BooProperties>",
    "description": ".....",
    "sourceType":"com.FooProperties"
  }],
  "hints":[{
    "name":"server.worker.group.keys",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I'm stuck. I cannot find any material about that on the Internet.

Best regards

Comment: this is because it would need value completion, which by my knowledge it does not have. with the map, the key as well as the value are variable and not pre defined, so IntelliJ does not know what to put there

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However I provided a `hint` in `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` file - but it is ignored

Comment: Moreover, I expect that IntelliJ autocompletes properties name for fields in `BooProperties` class

Comment: I think the hints autocompletion would only work for the value part of the config, not for the key. So if you are putting hints for `server.worker.group.keys` then I assume IntelliJ would give you these as autocompletion when you type `server.worker.group.keys: `

Comment: The sam thing actually happens in the class `JpaProperties`. It has a `Map` calles `properties`, and there is no autocompletion for that either.

Comment: Based on the Java class "Map<String, yourclass>", the annotation processor should recognize that keys can be custom. Below, it should continue with strictness, as yourclass can have well-defined property names in a POJO. Unfortunately it's not implemented like that. Autocompletion would not be expected for key type String, it only works well when your key is an enumeration.